# .NET Regex: How do I include "end of string only" character escape in a bracket expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I put the `\z` [character escape sequence for "end of string only"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#EndOnly) into a bracket statement like this: `[:a-z]`.  I've tried `[:a-z\z]`(*results in a literal "z"*) and `[:a-z\\z]` (*results in a literal "\" and literal "z"*).  I've also tried various permutations of brackets and parenthesis with similar result.

Comment: You can't, it is not a character specifically and it can have different meanings based on the options passed to the RegEx.  Why would you want to?  Maybe there's a better option?

Comment: Sounds like a [x-y-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, what are you actually trying to achieve

Comment: I usually use [^\\z]* which will get all character up to the control z character.

Comment: Only an alternation is possible: `([:a-z]|\z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a character class, `$` as well as `\z` and `\Z` (and `\b`, too) lose their "special" meaning of a zero-width assertion, and `\z` and `\Z` throw an exception as unknown escape sequences.

You can only use an alternation here:

```
(?:[:a-z]|\z)
```

This will match a `:` or a letter from `a-z` range, OR the very end of the string.